# Change value of variable after str_replace

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON value where I need to extract the values inside json and convert them in to a particular format. Please see my code below

```
<?php

 $jsonString ='{"generelist":{"genere1":"Adventure","genere2":"Action","genere3":"Action","genere4":"Action"}}';

 $obj = json_decode($jsonString,true);
 $genere=array();

 foreach ($obj['generelist'] as $key => $value) 
    {
        //echo "<br>------" . $key . " => " . $value;
        $genere[$key] = $value;

    }

 $val3=implode(' ', $genere);
 $val3=str_replace(' ', '=1 OR ', $val3);
 print $val3;
 ?>
```

The values of `$val3` are displaying like `Adventure=1` OR `Action=1` OR `Action=1` OR `Action`.

Now, I want to add `'=1'` to the last of the `$val3` like

`Adventure=1` OR `Action=1` OR `Action=1` OR `Action =1`

How can I add it?

Comment: Have you tried using [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)? Instead of that foreach?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do so, simply concat them.

```
$jsonString ='{"generelist":{"genere1":"Adventure","genere2":"Action","genere3":"Action","genere4":"Action"}}';

 $obj = json_decode($jsonString,true);
 $genere=array();

 foreach ($obj['generelist'] as $key => $value) 
    {
        //echo "<br>------" . $key . " => " . $value;
        $genere[$key] = $value;

    }

 $val3=implode(' ', $genere);
 $val3=str_replace(' ', '=1 OR ', $val3);
 $val3 .= '=1';
 print $val3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add last line:
`$val3 = $val3."=1";`

Answer (score 0):

Elegant variant using array_walk to add =1 to every genere, then joining them all with implode:

```
 $jsonString ='{"generelist":{"genere1":"Adventure","genere2":"Action","genere3":"Action","genere4":"Action"}}';
 $obj = json_decode($jsonString,true)['generelist'];

array_walk($obj,function(&$item1, $key){$item1="$item1=1";});
$string = implode(' OR ', $obj);
print $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as well :

```
$jsonString ='{"generelist":{"genere1":"Adventure","genere2":"Action","genere3":"Action","genere4":"Action"}}';
$obj = json_decode($jsonString,true);
$genere=array();
foreach ($obj['generelist'] as $key => $value) 
{
    //echo "<br>------" . $key . " => " . $value;
    $genere[$key] = $value."=1";
}

$val3=implode(' ', $genere);
$val3=str_replace(' ', 'OR ', $val3);
print $val3;
```